# Why does pg_restore fail silently in AWS ECS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Consider this pg_restore command:

```
pg_restore -h 123.123.123.123 -d my_database -U my_user --no-owner --no-privileges --no-password -t specific_table 616f6d35-202104.backup
```

When I run it locally it works. But when I run it my ECS instance it does not restore. There is no error and exit code is 0.

If I create the db in the statement (by adding the --create flag and changing my_database to postgres) like so:

```
pg_restore -h 123.123.123.123 -d postgres -U my_user --create --no-owner --no-privileges --no-password -t specific_table 616f6d35-202104.backup
```

It still works locally. When I run it in ECS it creates the db but still does not restore the table. And if I exclude the specific table:

```
pg_restore -h 123.123.123.123 -d my_database -U my_user --no-owner --no-privileges --no-password 616f6d35-202104.backup
```

Then it works. But it loads the whole database which I don't want. So it's something to do with the -t flag that works locally but not in my ECS instance.

**EDIT:**
There does seem to be a version mis-match. The closest I could get the environments was PostgreSQL **v10.16 on the ECS** and **v10.4 on the target EC2** that has the Postgres server 123.123.123.123. Still does not work. Could this be the issue? If so how do I install a specific minor version of postgresql or postgresql-client?

For the ECS in the docker file I have:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl ca-certificates gnupg
RUN curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt buster-pgdg main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-10
```

This gets me to v10.16 on the ECS (which still doesn't work). But if I change that last line to specify a specific minor version (to more closely match the EC2's version) it can't find it.

```
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-10.5

E: Unable to locate package postgresql-10.5
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-10.5'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-10.5'
```

Again, locally it works - and the version I have **locally is v10.5**.

**EDIT-2**:
I have a little more visibility on this. Looks like it outputs these two lines and then stops - still no error:

```
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: implied data-only restore
```

It seems 'implied data-only restore' might not be causing an issue though - there seems to be output that should come after it. But output just stops in my case.

Comment: does that table have any dependency that might not exists on ECS database?

Comment: How could I find that out? I looked up 'postgres table dependency' and found this postgres documentation on dependencies (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ddl-depend.html). But it doesn't describe how to screen a table for any/all dependencies.

Comment: so it was not foreign key , are you using any user-defined data type in that table for any of columns?

Comment: also seems you are not getting any error , I suspect that since you rae using local ip to connect to server , you are connecting to another server or instance

Comment: What is a 'user-defined data type'? Correct I am connecting from an ECS container to an EC2 instance.

Comment: I added an update regarding version mis-match

Comment: Have you tried using [`postgres:10.5`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/10.5/images/sha256-353e29f9957e1b35e8dc74b28096ea5a690e871c6f43e443594a5ea005b30287?context=explore) image in Dockerhub for your Docker image?

Comment: Yes, thanks. We created our own image with the exact same version. Still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out why the -t/--table flag wasn't working remotely. But I found a different solution that did exactly what I needed. I did this in Python but it can be done in bash or other languages.

I switched to the [-l list/-L use-list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html) flag.

```
 os.system(f'pg_restore -l {backup_file} > list1.list')
```

`pg_restore -l` outputs a .list file that looks something like this:

```
;
; Archive created at 2021-04-23 08:06:25
;     dbname: abc
;     TOC Entries: 2069
;     Compression: -1
;     Dump Version: 1.13-0
;     Format: CUSTOM
;     Integer: 4 bytes
;     Offset: 8 bytes
;     Dumped from database version: 9.6.16
;     Dumped by pg_dump version: 9.6.16
;
;
; Selected TOC Entries:
;
7380; 1262 16390 DATABASE - db9j0aedvewevi6fw ury3p1vgqirfm2wq
3; 2615 2200 SCHEMA - public ury3p1vgqirfm2wq
7381; 0 0 COMMENT - SCHEMA public ury3p1vgqirfm2wq
1; 3079 13308 EXTENSION - plpgsql 
7382; 0 0 COMMENT - EXTENSION plpgsql 
185; 1259 168687 TABLE public tableA ury3p1vgqirfm2wq
186; 1259 168693 TABLE public tableB ury3p1vgqirfm2wq
187; 1259 168699 TABLE public tableC ury3p1vgqirfm2wq
188; 1259 168702 TABLE public tableZ ury3p1vgqirfm2wq
```

The intention of this file is so that developers can restore by exclusion. They can peek in this file and comment out using `;` lines they don't want. Then they use `-L/--use-list` like `pg_restore --use-list=my_list.list -U username ...`.

Since all I needed was a few tables and their data (and needed to do it programmatically) I used the generated `.list` file to generate my own, abbreviated file. I learned (by trial and error) that the lines responsible for creating the table and populating its data say: `TABLE public tablename` and `TABLE DATA public tablename` respectively.

```
table_create = 'TABLE public '
table_data = 'TABLE DATA public '
```

So I looped over the `.list` file provided by `pg_restore -l` and looked for the lines for the needed tables. When I found the right lines I added them to a list.

```
table_names = ['tablename1', 'tablename2']
full_list = 'list1.list'
list_lines = []
with open(full_list) as topo_file:
    for line in topo_file:
        for table_name in table_names:
            if table_data + table_name + ' ' in line or table_create + table_name + ' ' in line:
                print(line)
                list_lines.append(line)
```

Then I used that list to create my own `.list` file.

```
restore_list = 'list2.list'
with open(restore_list, 'w') as f:
    for item in list_lines:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

I found the header was not necessary. So if I only wanted one table and its data the file would look very simple:

```
426; 1259 169557 TABLE public tablename1 ury3p1vgqirfm2wq
7130; 0 169557 TABLE DATA public tablename1 ury3p1vgqirfm2wq
```

If you notice the `;` comments things out. So anything after it pg_restore doesn't care about.
And finally I used that list file for in the `pg_restore` command.

```
restore_command = f'pg_restore --use-list={restore_list} --host=localhost --username=postgres --dbname=test --no-owner --no-privileges --verbose "{backup_file}"'
os.system(restore_command)
```

[pg_restore docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html) were the key - although I would have liked a little more context around the `.list` file syntax and structure.